# Migrate share folder to webshareing with Sharepoint services

Tags: sharepoint, shared-libraries

Hi all SharePoint Professional,

I am using Windows 2003 Server to share the file in our environment , as SharePoint Services 3.0 is free for Winodws 2003 Server , i would like to configure the ShareFolder available in SharePoint Document Libraries, I have already install sharepoint services in the server ,also in my shared folder properties' Web Sharing Tab i alredy select Share On: SharePoint Central Administration 
image:http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/8971/sharefolder.jpg

can someone kindly adive me what do i need to configure to see my windows shared folder in SharePoint Document Libraries.

Thaks,
Zayar

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a file share through SharePoint out of the box. 
You can import the files in your file share into SharePoint if that is what you mean?